# Removing TeX fonts from being system-wide

Tags: fonts, texlive

After reading [XeTeX can't find font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21941/xetex-cant-find-font) I executed

```
sudo cp $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

I am now trying out MathJax and I find that I need to remove the TeX fonts that were made system-wide so that I can test meaningfully. Is there any way to reverse the above process using the CLI?

FYI, I am on a Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit system running TeX Live 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your code seems to have copied `texlive-fontconfig.conf` to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`. You might simply want to delete that file from there.

```
sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

Comment: In Ubuntu you can try this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/font-manager-a-font-management-application-for-the-gnome-desktop.html

Comment: Or you can manually edit your ~/.fonts or ~/fonts.conf (I don't remember which one, as I no more use Linux.)

Comment: I am looking to reverse my steps *automatically*. I made them system-wide with two commands and am looking for one or two commands to disable them in the same way. To disable them one by one by hand using font management utilities means that one must recognize them, and then remove them, possibly one at a time, and not miss any. I will try that only as a last resort.

Comment: Well, your code seems to have copied texlive-fontconfig.conf to /etc/fonts/conf.d/. You might simply want to delete that file from there.

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and then again
`sudo fc-cache -fsv`

Comment: Thank you. Your last comment was what I was seeking and it seems so obvious in retrospect. Would you mind please updating your answer to reflect your last comment so that I could accept your answer? Thanks.